# devops: materialize Azure AD Security group

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to add an Azure AD security group (without mail/upn) to a Devops Permission with the rest api.
Is this possible?

In this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#add-an-aad-user-by-oid I see the following

> The body of the request must be a derived type of GraphUserCreationContext:
>
> GraphUserMailAddressCreationContext - Create a new user using the mail address as a reference to an existing user from an external AD or AAD backed provider.
> GraphUserOriginIdCreationContext - Create a new user using the OriginID as a reference to an existing user from an externalAD or AAD backed provider.
> GraphUserPrincipalNameCreationContext - Create a new user using the principal name as a reference to an existing user from an external AD or AAD backed provider.

The groups are created as universal security groups on our onprem AD, and synced to Azure AD.
I don't have a mailadress nor a UPN; but I can't find more info on what exactly OriginID is.

Edit; OriginID seems to work for a user, but not for a group.

Comment: The `OriginID` looks should be the `Object Id` of the group, navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the azure portal -> `Groups` -> find the group -> `Properties` -> try the `Object Id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an Azure AD group to Azure DevOps, you need to use the REST API [Groups - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#add-an-aad-group-by-oid).

```
POST https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Click [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#add-an-aad-group-by-oid) for an example. The `originId` in the request body is the Object id of your Azure AD group.

The REST API link your provide in the question is to create a user, not a group.

Comment: that implies I know the ObjectID of my group. I will have to use powershell and AzureAD cmdlets to get the objectID. But  I was indeed using the wrong URI

Comment: @Brtrnd `ObjectID` is required because you need to specify which group to operate on. For how to get the Object ID, you can refer to [Get-AzureADGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadgroup?view=azureadps-2.0).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up connecting with the Azure commandlets to get my ObjectID, as @jane-ma-msft suggested.